# Stressed syllable of באה

Tags: grammar-dikduk, korbanos-ketores-prayers

Yesterday I was looking at the text of how the incense had been prepared. In my ArtScroll book it is written:

> בֹּרִית כַּרְשִׁינָה לָמָה הִיא **בָֽאָה**

A bit later it says:

> אַחַת לְשִׁשִּׁים אוֹ לְשִׁבְעִים שָׁנָה הָיְתָה **בָאָה** שֶׁל שִׁירַֽיִם לַחֲצָאִין

In the first case a penultimate stress is marked with a *meteg,* while in the latter one the lack of mark indicates a final stress. I checked an Eshkol edition, and it had the same difference. The concordance lists multiple occurrences of both versions too. Shouldn't it be the same?

Comment: The stress change indicates a tense change

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted by [Rashi to Bereishit 29:6](https://www.sefaria.org/Rashi_on_Genesis.29.6?lang=bi), when the stress is on the penultimate syllable, the word is in the third person feminine singular perfect (past) tense, "it came". When the stress is on the final syllable, it is a (present tense) feminine singular participle, "is coming".

So it seems that ArtScroll are translating as follows:

> בֹּרִית כַּרְשִׁינָה לָמָה הִיא בָֽאָה
>
> Carshina lye, for what purpose did it come?

> אַחַת לְשִׁשִּׁים אוֹ לְשִׁבְעִים שָׁנָה הָיְתָה בָאָה שֶׁל שִׁירַֽיִם לַחֲצָאִין
>
> Once every sixty or seventy years the leftovers would be coming as half [of the required amount].

Of course, it's entirely possible that ArtScroll is mistaken and that the former instance is also supposed to be a feminine singular present participle with the stress on the final syllable. This would then read:

> Carshina lye, for what purpose does it come?

(The parallel sentence יין קפריסים למה הוא בא doesn't help us decide: בא is even more ambiguous than באה with no way to tell apart the third person masculine singular perfect from the masculine singular participle.)

Comment: If you could add a sentence on this issue, I'd be happy to accept your answer. Again, I understood the whole text in present tense, and this is how ArtScroll translates it, but from the Hebrew text perspective meteg can only be correct if it is in perfect tense.